# Why did F1 become the Help Key?

Tags: history, keyboards

There was actually a pretty big push among some vendors in the 1980's to have a dedicated Help Key (conveniently labeled as <kbd>Help</kbd>). Atari introduced it in 1983, and kept it to the end. The Commodore Amiga had it from the A1000 onward. I'm sure there are other vendors who tried. To my knowledge, the support for the dedicated Help Key in applications was kind of spotty.

But it was the <kbd>F1</kbd> key that would become the defacto standard for quickly accessing a "Help" function, and which we still follow today. How did this standard become popularized?

Comment: It was part of IBM's CUA: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_User_Access

Comment: Dumb anecdote: In the early 90's I had a really crappy job doing technical support for a cheap clone maker.  We actually had multiple users call for assistance when presented with a dialog saying "press any key to continue".  Apparently they were unsure which key was the "any key".  Fortunately, the junk keyboards we were selling had a blank key next to the space bar so we happily told users that was the 'any key'.  :-)

Comment: Apple introduced a 'help' key on the Apple Extended Keyboard in 1987 where 'insert' goes on a full-size PC keyboard, and kept it there on full-size keyboards for 20 years. It never really seemed to do much though, presumably because Apple has usually preferred smaller keyboards by default.

Comment: @Tommy Actually, if you use a standard PC keyboard with a Mac, it **still** calls Insert the Help key!

Comment: @seaturtle oh, that's surprising! They eliminated the text from the key with the aluminium keyboards. I guess you're looking at the keyboard viewer?

Comment: Sun Microsystems introduced it quite early and kept it to the end.

Comment: @Geo... You needed the keyboard [pictured here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Any_key)!

Comment: @Tommy, I was studying computer science a the time and was actually taught that "press a key" is far better than "press any key", since there is no "any" key, but "a" key is.

Comment: @TripeHound, thanks for the wiki link.  I had no idea that the 'what key should I press?' was as widespread as the article explains. - gotta love those end users.  :-)

Comment: The TI-99/4A didn't have a "Help" button ... but it did have an "AID" button (Function + 7). It wasn't used by the default ROM BASIC, but various expansion cartridges did use it for providing help.

Comment: The Commodore 128 and 16 also have a dedicated help key. You can list the line of the last BASIC error. So the Amiga 1000 was not the first Commodore with a help key.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

While general purpose function keys are something that had already been introduced in the 60s by manufacturers like Friden ([Flexowriter, 1965](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friden_Flexowriter#End_of_product_line)) or HP ([9810A, 1971](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_9800_series)), it wasn't until IBM's 3270 that function keys were widely available. 3270 terminals are block-orientated, which means all keystrokes, thus all editing, are local. Only the whole screen can be sent back (*1). The <kbd>PF</kbd> (and <kbd>PA</kbd>) keys are an exception to this as they deliver short predefined messages directly to the mainframe (*2), allowing the (mainframe) program to respond directly to such a request.

When *[CICS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CICS)* (developed in the late 60s) added [3270](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_3270) support (~1974), a help utility was added and by convention activated via <kbd>PF1</kbd>. Due to the asynchronous nature of <kbd>PF</kbd> key messages this enabled the addition of help information/screens to an existing application without modifying it (*3). Using <kbd>PF1</kbd> became the de facto standard for mainframe applications, not just with IBM and CICS.

When the PC became available, many professional programs did follow the same practice, but it wasn't until 1987 when IBM published their [Common User Access (CUA) guidelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access) as part of the [Systems Application Architecture (SAA) standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Systems_Application_Architecture), that <kbd>F1</kbd> as *Help* became the 'official' standard.

---

*1 - Well, not entirely true as a terminal can be ordered to send back either the whole screen, all fields, only modified fields, or marked regions. But that's part of the high art of block terminal programming.

*2 - Sending a message to the host - no matter if it's a full screen or a function key - always generates an input interrupt requesting attention and delivering the data (when served). A `PF` key delivers only two bytes of information (plus some header) which makes transmission, moving and handling way faster than a whole screen.

*3 - CICS is a Transaction Monitor, something that PC developers might call an application framework - or a program/window manager, or even an operating system. It offers a backbone structure where individual programs are 'just' function modules loaded into this framework and executed upon messages from the monitor program - like incoming screen (user input), network messages, lost connection or the like. In fact, they might only get loaded on demand and unloaded after handling such a message.

Much like a window manager can handle certain UI functionality without activating a user program, CICS can offer to handle (some) function keys without activating any user module. Doing help screens is one of these offers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78930/discussion-on-answer-by-raffzahn-why-did-f1-become-the-help-key).

Answer (score 11):

As Ross Ridge mentioned in a comment, it was part of IBM's Common User Access guidelines. These guidelines were based in part on the behaviour of existing "killer apps" for PC - which at the time mostly meant office applications.

The spreadsheet software Lotus 1-2-3 used <kbd>F1</kbd> for help from its first release in 1983, as can be seen in the manual available [here](https://winworldpc.com/product/lotus-1-2-3/1x), and in the four years between its release and IBM releasing the CUA would become the preeminent spreadsheet application ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_1-2-3)).

Comment: Not realy. Most of the CUA was based arround the existing 3270/CICS world  and rather adapted to PC use. It's goal was to provide similar handling all across IBM products. And lets be honest, it's way less work to tell new programs how to handle user input than to modify software already existign for decades :))

Answer (score 8):

I was working as a programmer at WordPerfect in the late 80's and someone there decided to leave it where it had been on the DG machine and put the help key on the <kbd>F3</kbd> key on the PC also. Microsoft put it on the  <kbd>F1</kbd> key in all their Windows products and it seemed everyone else followed suit. In later versions, WordPerfect also moved to the <kbd>F1</kbd> key and I have not seen any deviations since. I always thought the  <kbd>F1</kbd> key made more sense.

Comment: This is just about an answer to the question. If you'd like to share your WordPerfect development stories I'd appreciate it if you could write a post or two for our much neglected [meta-tag:blog]. You might also find the [tour] interesting, if you want to get acquainted with the Stack Exchange model.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the 3270 terminals described by Raffzahn, there were also the 5250 range.  These were used by IBM's midrange systems: S/34, S/36, S/38, and AS/400.  The AS/400 lives on today but has been through many name changes: iSeries, System i, and now IBM i (that list might not be complete).

They operated similarly to the 3270 terminals but they were not compatible.  They were also block oriented.  A typical screen contained a mix of literals, output fields, input fields, and both (input / output) fields.  The user could only enter to the input or both fields. The data would only be sent to the host when Enter or one of a limited number of other keys was pressed.  Depending on the key, all of the input data would be returned or just the event that the key had been pressed.  The Enter key always sends the data.  The function keys might or might not send the data at the programmer's choice.  A few other keys would cause the screen to be submitted, these would either always send the data (e.g. page keys) or never send the data (help key).  The reason that the help key did not send data is that sending triggered the simple local validation (e.g. required entry); if help triggered this then the user could not use help to find out why the data was invalid.  An annoying consequence was that when you exited help, you found that all of you entries had been lost.

All (at least all that I know) 5250 terminals had dedicated **Help** keys.  SSA / CUA came in between the S/3x models and the AS/400.  Prior to that **F1** was usually exit.  After that, **F3** became exit and **F1** typically duplicated **Help** (but a mean programmer could define then differently).

The most primitive of these terminals that I have encountered was the 5251.  Search for **IBM 5251** for plenty of images.  These were huge and very heavy.  You could imagine driving a truck over them and they would survive.  We used to nickname them "Russian TVs".

On the older devices, some keys were odd by today's standards.  **Enter** was where the right **Ctrl** key is today.  The key in the position of the modern **Enter** was **Field Exit** which cleared the remainder of the current field and moved to the next.  It did not submit the screen to the host.  **Page Up** and **Page Down** were **Roll Down** and **Roll Up** with **Roll Down** corresponding to **Page Up** and vice versa.  The oldest models had no dedicated function keys.  There was a single key called **Cmd**.  You pressed this followed by **1** to **9** (not on the numeric pad) for **F1** to **F9**.  Note followed by not together as **Shift**, **Alt**, or **Ctrl** are typically used.  **F10** was **Cmd** and **0**, **F11** was **Cmd** and **-**, **F12** was **Cmd** and **=**.    **F13** through **F24** were similar to **F1** to **F12** but shifted the second key.  So **F16** was **Cmd** and **Shift+4** and **F24** was **Cmd** and **Shift+=**.  This applied even on non-US keyboards where the shifted numeric keys might have different normal values.  In these days, it was typical to call then command keys rather than function keys.  Later terminals switched to a more modern style with a separate row of 12 keys labelled **F1** to **F12**.  Some had a second row for **F13** to **F24**.

Comment: Spent 9 years doing Java on an AS/400.  Interesting times.  The 5250 emulator for Windows from IBM is perhaps the most rock solid software I've ever used.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yeah, it is fairly solid but not perfect.  It did not cope very well with an interruption with the connection to the host.  It would drop the session due to only a brief interruption.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I remember my first 5250 emulator installed into my early IBM PC.  It was a hardware card, not just software, and used the massive twinax cable of the day.